# Tracing a program with multiple forks in if/else block

Tags: c, fork, system, system-calls

I'm trying to trace this program. I see that it outputs 4 times when I run it, but I don't understand why.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() 
{
    if (fork() == 0)
        fork();
    else 
    {
        fork();
        fork();
        printf("%d\n", getpid());
    }
}
```

To my knowledge, the if/else forks my program, then if we're in the child, it forks again. If we're in the parent, it runs the code in the else block. I get confused when I try to trace after this point, though.

- Once the else statement forks again, aren't we in another child?
- When do the children stop being spawned?

Comment: In the `else` block, the first `fork()` duplicates the process then each duplicate runs the second `fork()` that produces two more processes. In the end there are 4 processes that reach the `printf()` statement.

Comment: the `else` block is accessed only by one process (the parent of the 1st `fork()`), then there are two calls to `fork()`.

Comment: Oh, okay! Thank you guys! I get it now.

Comment: You'll still see 4 prints if you didn't have `if` part and your program contained just the code inside `else` part. Can you understand that how works?

Comment: @Jake consider writing your own answer then.

Comment: @P.P. I understand how that works, I think the if statement was confusing me. So, just to be clear... the children fork and die without printing, since they don't execute what's in the else block. The parent of the first child executes the code in the else block only, and all children spawned from the else block only use the next line(s) of the else block. Is that correct?

Comment: @考えネロク I can do that!

Comment: @Jake Pretty much, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After getting it explained for me, I understand it now.

The first fork will spawn a child (let's call it c1):

```
if (fork() == 0)
```

The return value of fork is 0 when you're in the child. So, c1 will execute the if statement block:

```
fork();
```

The child created here, c2 (as well as c1) will both die, as they aren't going to execute the else block.

---

Meanwhile, the parent process will execute the else block.

```
fork();
```

This creates another child of the original parent process (c3). c3 will execute the next fork in the else block.

```
fork();
```

Now, we'll have c4, too.

---

Meanwhile, the original parent process will still have a fork that hasn't run. This creates the final child process, c5.

At the end of the run, there will be 4 prints: The original parent process, c3, c4, and c5.

Answer (score 1):

1. `fork` in `if` is executed. There are two processes now child C1 and parent. Parent gets a non-zero number. Child gets `0`.
2. Parent enters else block as it got non-zero return from `fork`. Now again there are two processes child C2 and parent - after executing `fork` in else block.
3. Parents fork again with C3.
4. Child C2 forks again with C4.
5. Note that C1 also forked but it will not do anything other than ending the `if` block. (We don't care about this).

So `4`, `printf` execution - one by Parent, `C2`, `C3` and `C4`.

The key one line Golden rule is:-

> *Both parent and child process start their execution **right after the system call fork()***

And each process ends when the control reaches the end of the `function` here it is `main()`. (Answering your last question).